# Iterate array of objects with string array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects (JAVASCRIPT) like below

```
 [
        {
            "code": "123",
            "label": "Test123"
        },
        {
            "code": "234",
            "label": "Test"
        },
        {
            "code": "980",
            "label": "joe"
        }
    ]
```

And i have a string array like below

```
["123", "234"]
```

I want to loop through array of objects and pass string array to get the "label"

I am expecting an output like below

```
[
        {
            "code": "123",
            "label": "Test123"
        },
        {
            "code": "234",
            "label": "Test"
        }
    ]
```

Please let me know if there is any efficient solution (JAVASCRIPT) because my array of objects is big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const obj =  [
  {
    "code": "123",
    "label": "Test123"
  },
  {
    "code": "234",
    "label": "Test"
  },
  {
    "code": "980",
    "label": "joe"
  }
];

const arr = ["123", "234"];

var output = arr.flatMap(item => obj.filter(x => x.code == item));
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Edited to be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is big, this can help to use `Array.reduce`.

```js
const input = [{
    "code": "123",
    "label": "Test123"
  },
  {
    "code": "234",
    "label": "Test"
  },
  {
    "code": "980",
    "label": "joe"
  }
]

const input2 = ["123", "234"];

const inputObj =input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur.code] = cur.label;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = input2.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  if (inputObj[cur]) {
    acc.push({
      code: cur,
      label: inputObj[cur]
    });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```